# Change the style of already shown wicket ModalWindow

Tags: css, updates, wicket-1.6, modal-window

I want to make modal window transprent (opacity:0.5) after a click event in one of its buttons. 
I try by using :

```
window.add(AttributeAppender.append("style","color:red; font-weight:bold")); 
or 
window.setCssClassName("custom-modal");
```

But none of these solutions allows to apply the desired style.

Any help will be grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method below of ModalWindow.

> setMaskType( ModalWindow.MaskType.SEMI_TRANSPARENT );

check the example:

```
            final ModalWindow modal;
            add( modal = new ModalWindow( "modal" ) );

            modal.setCookieName( "modal window" );

            modal.setResizable( false );
            modal.setAutoSize( true );
            modal.setCssClassName( ModalWindow.CSS_CLASS_GRAY );

            modal.setPageCreator( new ModalWindow.PageCreator()
            {
                @Override
                public Page createPage()
                {
                    return new alertPopup( modal );
                }
            } );

            AjaxLink backButton = new AjaxLink<Void>( "previous-button" )
            {
                @Override
                public boolean isVisible()
                {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick( AjaxRequestTarget target )
                {
                    modal.setMaskType( ModalWindow.MaskType.SEMI_TRANSPARENT );
                    modal.show( target );
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your solution doesn't work, is that wicket does not use ModalWindow's `<div>` to show the actual modal in the screen, but creates a new `<div>` of class wicket-modal instead.

So instead of changing ModalWindow's `<div>` style, all you have to do is find `<div class='.wicket-modal'>` and append the new opacity.

Here is a trivial example:

```
final ModalWindow modal = new ModalWindow("modal");
    modal.setTitle("Trivial Modal");

    AjaxLink<Void> modalLink = new AjaxLink<Void>("modalLink") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            target.appendJavaScript("var originalStyle = $('.wicket-modal').attr('style');"
                    + "$('.wicket-modal').attr('style', originalStyle + 'opacity: 0.5;');");
        }
    };
    Fragment modalFragment = new Fragment(modal.getContentId(), "modalContent", this);
    modalFragment.add(modalLink);
    modal.setContent(modalFragment);

    add(modal);
    add(new AjaxLink<Void>("openModal") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            modal.show(target);
        }
    });
```

And the html file:

```
<div wicket:id="modal"></div>
<wicket:fragment wicket:id="modalContent">
  <div wicket:id="modalLink">Change opacity</div>
</wicket:fragment>
<div wicket:id="openModal">Press me</div>
```